# Error by putting a random Number in a variable

Tags: kotlin

```
import kotlin.random.Random
var rnd = {Random.nextInt(0,100)}
print(rnd)
```

In the console the result is () -> kotlin.Int

Comment: I found the error i am so stupid :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `{Random.nextInt(0,100)}` (note the `{}`) is a function literal in form of a [lambda expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions), specifying exactly what's printed in the console: A function that takes no arguments and returns an `Int`.
Since functions in Kotlin are first-class citizens, it can be stored in variables and printed just the same as any other value.